# PC can't log into SQL Server on different peer network

Tags: networking, sql-server, sql, tcpip

I have a basic peer network (WORKGROUP) with PCs connected to sql server 2008 on a Windows 7 machine. I took one XP pc and the server home and connected to the server with no problems. When I plugged them back in at the office, I got the following error with my sql server tcpip odbc connection (sql server login not windows auth):

```
---------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Login
---------------------------
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 67
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

The next day I took a different client machine running windows 7 and the server home again. The client could login fine but when I plugged them back in at the office I got the same issue. I can ping the server no problems and share files. Same problem with Firewall turned off on all machines. TPC enabled on server port 1433. The two client machines cant log in using SQL server management studio either when they were working fine before.

All other pcs which remained in the office can still connect no problem.

Comment: Log in via SSMS on the SQL server machine itself, and check the accounts and permissions.

Comment: In ssms logins are unchanged. All clients are connecting using the same sqlserver login and pwd

Comment: faulty client can see the server instance using osql -l

Comment: error - both clients (the xp and the windows 7 one) are 32bit but the server is 64bit

Comment: using ms network monitor from client gets 'Icmp: Destination Unreachable Message, Port Unreachable, 81.200.**.**:1434'

Comment: Is the ODBC connection connecting via the server name or the ip address?

Comment: server name or ip same result. It looks like these clients are trying to connect via isp dns lookup whereas the others are connecting directly to the server

Comment: If the ODBC connection is connecting via ip address then name resolution (DNS) shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Connecting via ip doesnt work either but its not clear what the error is in the network monitor

Comment: rebooted router and pc and can connect via ip but not servername

Comment: I vaguely remember having the same issue a couple of yrs ago when I changed router and ended up having to code all the connection strings by ip address.

Comment: -Allocated the client a static IP in its TCPIPv4 settings identical to its DHCP asigned IP
-reserved that address in the netgear router lan ip table
-ipconfig /release
-ipconfig /renew
-rebooted pc and router

Now connects via servername

Answer (score 1):

- Allocated the client a static IP in its TCPIPv4 settings identical to its DHCP assigned IP
- Reserved that address in the netgear router lan ip table
- `ipconfig /release`
- `ipconfig /renew`
- Rebooted pc and router now connects via servername
- Took both home again and back without issue

Comment: Great to see that you found a solution to your problem. Please come back and put this answer as your accepted one, so that it won't stay open (and get repeatably bumped up).